# Using global vars to include css

Tags: html, css, variables, path, global

I've tried to include the css from a global var but styles are not included.

Global vars:

```
<?php 

require_once '../app/init.php';
define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
define('CSS_DIR', ROOT_DIR . '\css');
define('CSS_BOOTSTRAP', CSS_DIR . '\bootstrap.min.css');
define('CSS_STYLES', CSS_DIR . '\styles.css');       

$app = new App;
```

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap Login Form</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
            <link href='<?php echo CSS_BOOTSTRAP; ?>' rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link href='<?php echo CSS_STYLES; ?>' rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>
```

Code from browser:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap Login Form</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\xampp\htdocs\grade_your_room\public\css\bootstrap.min.css" >
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\xampp\htdocs\grade_your_room\public\css\styles.css" >


</head>
<body>
```

If i try to acces the path C:\xampp\htdocs\grade_your_room\public\css\styles.css the styles can be showed.

Comment: `link`'s `href` attribute must have a relative/absolute link as a value, not a local path. It therefore should be: `<link href="/css/styles.css" >` if the domain you are is, indeed, targeting your `C:\xampp\htdocs\grade_your_room\public` folder (check Apache's vhost configuration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal `dirname` (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) returns parent directory's path in local!

You should set `ROOT_DIR` to your domain name (localhost for your development).

```
<?php
require_once '../app/init.php';
define('ROOT_DIR', 'localhost');
define('CSS_DIR', ROOT_DIR . '/css');
define('CSS_BOOTSTRAP', CSS_DIR . '/bootstrap.min.css');
define('CSS_STYLES', CSS_DIR . '/styles.css');
```

Comment: Thank you, one last question. It's a good idea use global var's to link the css and js or not?

Comment: For me yes, I have done the same when I was building my own framework.